pon will fail in startup but sending AT commands directly with minicom won't
I have a SIM LTE modem that use "pon" to connect. This pon use a chat script that send the AT commands needed to connect.
when I try to start the ppp service, the AT commands all fail by timeout:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pon
pppd options in effect:
debug           # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
updetach                # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
persist         # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
dump            # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
noauth          # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
remotename 3gppp                # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
/dev/ttyUSB3            # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
115200          # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
lock            # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
connect chat -s -v -f /etc/chatscripts/chat-connect -T internet.x              # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
disconnect chat -s -v -f /etc/chatscripts/chat-disconnect               # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
nocrtscts               # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
modem           # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
asyncmap 0              # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-failure 4              # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-interval 30            # (from /etc/ppp/options)
hide-password           # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
novj            # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
novjccomp               # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
ipcp-accept-local               # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
ipcp-accept-remote              # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
ipparam 3gppp           # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
noipdefault             # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
ipcp-max-failure 30             # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
defaultroute            # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
usepeerdns              # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
noccp           # (from /etc/ppp/peers/provider)
noipx           # (from /etc/ppp/options)
abort on (BUSY)
abort on (NO CARRIER)
abort on (NO DIALTONE)
abort on (ERROR)
abort on (NO ANSWER)
timeout set to 30 seconds
send (AT^M)
expect (OK)
^M
alarm
Failed
Script chat -s -v -f /etc/chatscripts/chat-connect -T internet.x finished (pid 2017), status = 0x3

Now, If I run all the commands that are preset in the /etc/chatscripts/chat-connect script using minicom, the answer for those commands are instant:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB3 -b 115200

Welcome to minicom 2.8

OPTIONS: I18n
Port /dev/ttyUSB3, 16:08:09

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

AT

OK
ATE0

OK
AT+CPIN?

+CPIN: READY

OK
AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 16,99

OK
AT+CREG?

+CREG: 0,5

OK
AT+CGREG?

+CGREG: 0,5

OK
AT+COPS?

+COPS: 0,0,"XXX",0

OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.x",,0,0

OK
ATD*99#

CONNECT 150000000



There are no delays, no waits. The OK are received instantly. Not sure what is happening. I still don't see the ppp0 connection with ifconfig tho.

Some pieces of hardware take some time to initialize after a restart. Could you move your "starting the PPP server" to sometime later in your startup sequence? Or loop on getting a response to ATH0, or a timeout. If it says OK, do the PPP startup, but if "timeout", sleep and try again.

What is strange is that the same commands using minicom will respond instantly.. not sure why during the chat script they get stuck
